# What verb is used for "leading" a dance in (Colombian) Spanish?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, colombia

In Argentina, they use 'manejar' ("to drive") as the verb describing what the tango leader does to the follower.  I'm now taking classes in salsa caleña (Colombian style salsa), and they don't use 'manejar'.  Someone suggested "llevar".  Does anyone know what the proper verb is in Colombia?

Comment: Wikipedia on [tango](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tango) says: _en la pareja de tango es el hombre quien crea y **dirige** el baile y la mujer es quien lo sigue_, so the verb _dirigir_ can also apply to at least tango.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the thesis [*La corporalidad de la mujer en el baile de la salsa. El escenario y el bar como lugares de teatralización de la feminidad*](http://200.24.17.74:8080/jspui/bitstream/fcsh/486/3/Garc%C3%ADaManuela_2016_Corporalidadmujerbailesalsa.pdf) by the anthropologist Manuela García Arango, of Universidad de Antioquia in Medellín, Colombia.

It is comprehensive description on the genre roles in the salsa dance.

From it we can gather some terminology:

- The action: **liderar, indicar, dirigir, guiar**
- The role: **conductor, guía, dirigente**

See here some quotes of it:

> La salsa como muchos de los bailes latinos mantiene una relación de poder entre el rol masculino y femenino donde el primero es quien **crea, lidera e indica los movimientos** a la mujer mientras esta, completamente dócil y dispuesta, ejecuta las órdenes del hombre. El hombre como mente maestra del baile, debe tener claro que el objetivo es la exhibición de la mujer, es decir, la mujer es mostrada en el baile como objeto de deseo y, como afirma Mulvey, sujeta a la mirada masculina. Sin embargo las bailarinas no mantienen un rol pasivo, ellas actúan de manera que puedan ser deseadas, personificando una feminidad con el fin de llamar la atención de esa mirada masculina. (43)
>
> Siguiendo a Desmond, el baile como un reflejo de la cultura retrata elementos que la constituyen, por lo tanto, el hecho que sea el hombre quien invite a bailar y el **conductor** del mismo baile no es fortuito, es una clara representación de una larga tradición patriarcal en la que a lo masculino se le ha otorgado el control de cada situación, mientras la mujer, que socialmente se le ha otorgado el rol de lo sensitivo debe responder a los **direccionamientos** masculinos desde su cuerpo. (71)
>
> Los roles de género reflejan nuevos matices cuando son las mujeres quienes **dirigen** el baile, ya sea porque el hombre no conoce los códigos y toman el control de la situación o porque deciden bailar con otras mujeres, dado el caso, una de ellas toma el rol de **guía** mientras la otra responde a las indicaciones de su compañera. (74)
>
> Continúa la noche e invito a bailar a mi amigo, debido a su experiencia en el baile conoce bien los códigos pero en este caso yo **dirijo** el baile, mi cuerpo y mi mente adquieren una disposición de control de la situación, nos ubicamos frente a frente y él espera mi señal, yo pongo mi mano derecha sobre su omoplato y la izquierda toma su mano derecha a la vez que pone su mano izquierda sobre mi hombro e iniciamos el baile. Mi mente y mi cuerpo ya se han hecho uno, la naturalización de los códigos cumple su función y no debo pensar mucho qué pasos deseo hacer pues la energía que pasa por mis manos los indica con firmeza y mi compañero dispuesto, sigue cada una de mis indicaciones. En este momento es él quien se luce en medio de los giros que le indico. La gente nos observa, claramente no es “natural” que sea el hombre quien gire constantemente y sea el exhibido, esa es la función tradicional de la mujer, no obstante continuamos bailando, disfrutamos la transgresión. Sigo atenta al ritmo de la música para encontrar los movimientos adecuados, de repente inicia el mambo de la canción, que corresponde a la descarga instrumental tan común en la salsa, suelto entonces sus manos y los cuerpos se mueven frente a frente con libertad, cada uno se deja llevar por la música con fuerza y energía para responder a la demanda de los instrumentos, en ese momento recupero los códigos femeninos y muevo todo mi cuerpo enfatizando en mis pies y caderas como siempre se me inculcó en los procesos de aprendizaje, frente a frente bailamos hasta que termina la descarga, inmediatamente tomo mi rol de **dirigente** y de nuevo le indico los movimientos próximos a seguir, pasos de salsa caleña, giros de porro, no hay una reglas que censuren nuestros movimientos mientras se encuentren dentro del ritmo de la canción y el conteo de la salsa que ya tenemos mecanizado 1, 2, 3... 5, 6, 7...). La canción termina y volvemos a nuestra mesa. (76)
>
> Por otro lado los cuerpos de las bailadoras responden a un habitus que se refleja en las relaciones de género de la sociedad, así las cosas, estas mujeres responden en el baile social al estereotipo de docilidad mientras el hombre se constituye como la mente que **controla** y **guía** el baile. (86)

Answer (score 1):

"Llevar" is not exactly what you want. Something better would be "guiar", "liderar" or "encabezar".

"Encabezar" is the most precise one in this case.

Comment: Hey guys, this is a **new contributor here**, but not a newcomer to the Stacks. It would be good to bring them up to speed here by providing helpful comments about what can be improved or why this post deserves a downvote, not just downvoting without providing any guidance or explanation. Point to [ask]/[answer] or even [tour] and [help] if you consider so, but it is in our community's best interest that we are not penalizing new users with downvotes without helping them to understand how to become valuable contributors. Thank you all. Thanks Eugenio for your contribution Welcome to the stack

Comment: Eugenio, I do't know why you received the downvote. This question has the tag "colombia". I don't know if you want to elaborate more about "Encabezar" being preferable over "llevar" in Colombian Spanish. To me (I'm from Spain) "llevar" would be the correct verb for somebody leading their dance partner (a couple dancing). "Encabezar" would have the connotation of a larger group of dancers, if anything. You could "encabezar una conga" but it's not what I would normally use for a dance (much less the dance of a couple). You can "encabezar un desfile". It is different in Colombia?